# Tkinter buttons and entrybox

Tags: python, tkinter, grid-layout

How can I move the buttons around the grid in the code below? Whenever I try by changing the row and column nothing happens. Also, is it possible to make the textbox bigger, so that I can put sentences there, as of now the text goes off the box?

```
from Tkinter import*

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        global e
        global b
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        b=Entry(bg = 'yellow')
        b.grid(row=19, column=40)
        e=Entry(bg = 'grey')
        e.grid(row=15, column = 1000)
        self.buttons()

    def instructions(self):
        b.insert(0, 'HI')   

    def start_game(self):
        e.insert(0, "I want to put a sentance here")

    def buttons(self):
        self.b = Button(self, text = "Instructions", command = self.instructions)
        self.b.grid(row=15, column = 25)

        self.b1 = Button(self, text = "Start Game", command = self.start_game)
        self.b1.grid(row=10, column = 10)

root = Tk()
root.title("Box")
root.geometry("400x400")        
app=Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I fixed your indentation.  Please check to make sure I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

To move the buttons around in the grid, you simply change the row and column. You say that doesn't work, but you must be doing something wrong -- that's exactly how you do it.

I notice the example code is trying to put something in column 1000. Assuming you don't have anything in the other columns except for columns 10, 25 and 40, all other columns will be of zero width so it will appear as if this object is in the fourth column.

To make the text box bigger, give it a bigger width:

```
b=Entry(bg = 'yellow', width=100)
```

Another way to make it bigger is to force the column it is in to be a bigger size.